# selecting data based on condition in python

Tags: python

So far I've been able to solve most problems by looking at old threads but this time I couldn't find anything that I could relate to my current problem so I'm going to try and ask my own question.

I'm new to Python and trying to load some data based on a condition in the data. My script looks like this:

```
infoPRD = []
with open('SpectraPRDinfo.txt') as inputfile:
for line in inputfile:
    infoPRD.append(line.strip().split(' '))

datesPRD = []

for j in range(2,len(infoPRD),2):
    datesPRD.append(float(infoPRD[j][3]))
```

So with this I retrieve the information in my text file and write a list of the values in one of the columns. The result is

> [['fitsName', 'OBJECT', 'DATE-OBS', 'MJD-OBS', 'SNR'],
>    [''],
>
> ['ADP.2016-03-18T01_03_02.067.fits',
>     'Proxima-Centauri',
>     '2016-03-17T09:05:48.326',
>     '57464.37903156',
>     '3.9'],
>    [''],
>
> ['ADP.2016-09-09T09_40_26.314.fits',
>     'Proxima-Centauri',
>     '2016-02-15T09:13:39.222',
>     '57433.38448174',
>     '26.2'],
>    [''],

etc. and all the dates (the MJD-OBS) is loaded into a the list called datesPRD.

So what I need to do is to only consider the data where the last value ('SNR') is higher than a given value (e.g. 10). So either I should just skip the lines when loading in the files if the SNR value is too low or I could remove the data afterwards. I guess the first option would be preferable but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is arranged into rows and columns separated by a character, you should use the `csv` module to process it.

```
import csv
with open(filename, newline='') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=' ')
    datesPRD = [float(row['SNR']) for row in r if float(row['SRD']) > 10]
```

Comment: This selects the SNR row but is easily changed to dates which is what you meant. More importantly it is easy to extract any one of the other columns in the file following the same procedure. It works like a charm and is really helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You do this by iterating through all the lines and skipping ones which don't have the last value more than 10.

Of course, we have to skip lines that do not have enough elements and convert our number from string to decimal type.

```
for line in datesPRD[1:]:
    if len(line) > 5:
        if decimal(line[4]) >= 10:
            # Do something with the line here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
with open('SpectraPRDinfo.txt', 'r') as inputfile:
    infoPRD = [x.split(' ') for x in inputfile.readlines()
               if x and int(x.split(' ')[-1]) > 10]
```